# How to create new user in Linux using nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, child-process

Below is the code i'm using to run linux command it run but, doesn't show anything in terminal to set new password, group nothing. terminal just runs forever and doesn't exit.

````
   const child = execFile('sudo',['adduser', 'gku5'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
   console.log(stdout);
   }); ```
````

Comment: I think the `execFile` isn't the intention here, which executes an external command and returns the buffered output. `spawn` is what you may be looking for. It creates a new shell and returns streaming I/O, with which you can interact. Do study [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node) to understand the difference. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044587/6519224) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is not adduser, but useradd. For instance, i want to add new user named kbr. The command will be like this-

```
sudo useradd kbr
```

Your program should look like this-

```js
   const child = execFile('sudo',['useradd', 'gku5'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
   console.log(stdout);
   });
```

And about the output. useradd shows output in RHEL, but it doesn't happen in other distribution. Please refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537145/verbose-useradd-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux) for this.

About the output, you can cat the auth.log file to show the output.
For instance,
`cat /var/log/auth.log | tail -1` 
would show, something like this,

```
Jan 27 19:04:16 useradd[32328]: failed adding user 'kbr', data deleted
```

So, the program should look like this-

```js
child = exec('sudo useradd kbr | cat /var/log/auth.log | tail -1',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('output: ' + stdout);
        if (error !== null) {
             console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried using adduser same thing happens

Comment: Check this answer again, please.

Comment: this is the output i got ```output: Jan 27 19:42:49 vaita-desktop sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)```

exec error: